# Import Phaser in Aurelia

Tags: phaser-framework, aurelia

I want to use [Phaser](https://phaser.io/) in an aurelia CLI application using typescript,
npm install runs properly, and I have already modified aurelia.json as follows

```
 ...
 {
     "name": "phaser",
     "path": "../node_modules/phaser/build",
     "main": "phaser"
 },
 ....
```

When I try to use phaser in a ts file, it says phaser is undefined. And in fact, looking cli onsole, doesn't seem to be tracking phaser. If I change dependency name to something like "phaserjs", it starts tracing it, but of course I cannot use it because the import requires another name.

```
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import * as phaser from "phaser";

@autoinject
export class Login {
    attached():void{
        console.log("this print undefined", Phaser);
    }
}
```

I have tried using import * as phaser from "phaser", import {Game} from "phaser" and nothing seems to work.
However, looking at vendor-bundle.js, phaser.js lines are found. So I do not know why I cannot use it

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

For someone with same issue later:
Phaser 2x was not designed to be modular,. To be able to use it you need to exports a couple of dependencies it requires.
First, use phaser-ce (Community-edition), it has support for webpack.
Second, export its dependencies:

In aurelia using requirejs, modify aurelia.json vendor dependencies.

```
     {
        "name": "pixi",
        "path": "../node_modules/phaser-ce/build/custom",
        "main": "pixi",
        "exports": ["PIXI"]
      },
      {
        "name": "p2",
        "path": "../node_modules/phaser-ce/build/custom",
        "main": "p2",
        "exports": ["p2"]
      },
      {
        "name": "phaser-ce",
        "path": "../node_modules/phaser-ce/build/custom",
        "main": "phaser-split",
        "exports": ["Phaser"]
      },
```

Now you can use phaser without problems

```
import * as Phaser from "phaser-ce";
```

Phaser-CE also includes typescripts definitions inside its module folder "typings"